# Generic function that accepts Vec<u32> and Vec<f32>

Tags: generics, rust

I want to define a function to calculate the median of a vector that contains either f32 or u32 values, or possibly all numeric types. f32 and u32 are my current use cases.

I don't think I understand generics or traits sufficiently. The best I could do is below, where I specify that the generic type parameter T needs to implement some traits to allow mathematical operations. If possible I would also like to cast the return type to be f32 rather than T.

```rust
fn median<T: Add<Output = T> + From<f32> + Div<Output = T>>(array: &Vec<T>) -> T {
    if (array.len() % 2) == 0 {
        let ind_left = array.len() / 2 - 1;
        let ind_right = array.len() / 2;
        (array[ind_left] + array[ind_right]) / 2.0
    } else {
        array[(array.len() / 2)]
    }
}
```

But this has a problem on line 5:

```
mismatched types
expected type parameter `T`
             found type `{float}`rustcE0308
```

I could use map to convert the vector of one type to the other, but that feels like unnecessary work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first problem is that `2.0` is a float literal, it's not a `T`. `T` can be *anything* which implements the specified traits.

So you need to convert `2.0` to `T` for it to work:

```
(array[ind_left] + array[ind_right]) / T::from(2.0)
```

Then you'll have a second problem, which is that `array[ind_right]` tries to copy the item out, but you have not told that the object *can* be copied. This requires an additional bound of `Copy` (or `Clone` then an explicit `Clone` call).

> If possible I would also like to cast the return type to be f32 rather than T.

Then you need to add a type bound of `Into<f32>`.

In fact I don't think the `From<f32>` is correct or useful: that lets you convert `2.0`, but at the end of the day the only things convertible from f32 are f32 and f64.

Probably more useful would be the abiliy to convert to an f32, then working entirely on f32s internally. That means you need no other trait bound than that (and Copy):

```rust
fn median<T: Into<f32> + Copy>(array: &[T]) -> f32 {
    if (array.len() % 2) == 0 {
        let ind_left = array.len() / 2 - 1;
        let ind_right = array.len() / 2;
        (array[ind_left].into() + array[ind_right].into()) / 2.0
    } else {
        array[(array.len() / 2)].into()
    }
}
```

That's still not great tho, because Rust is very conservative in its implementation of `From`: only u8, i8, u16, and i16 are convertible that way, because a single-precision float (f32) only has 24 bits of precision, meaning it can't represent every 32 bit integer.

And casting is not generic in Rust.

So you probably want to check out `num`, it might have number-conversion traits which work for this sort of scenario.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In your code example, it seems things work just fine if I work with f64 instead of f32. Changing that in both the Into<f64> and return type requirements seems to be without issues. Are there pitfalls to take into account? 

That solution is slightly different than my initial question asked for, but works for me.

Comment: @WouterDeCoster f64 has 53 bits of precisions so you can convert from f32, i32, and u32 just fine. However i64 and u64 won't work (and f64 tend to be a bit to a lot slower because they take more space and thus cache but whether that's relevant depends on your workload). If you don't care then it's fine.

Comment: In terms of f64 being slower, that only applies to the return value here right? As the median itself is in this case calculated for u32 and f32, only to be converted to f64 at the end?

Comment: Technically the median in in fact calculated in f64. However I assume what will happen is the two values will be loaded in registers, then you'll have either a no-op (for float inputs) or a register->register conversion from integer to double, then the addition and division in registers, before returning the value. So the double won't hit memory at any point, and thus space concerns are not really an issue,